# Jenkins credentials for cloning a github repository via ssh when deploying

Tags: github, jenkins, oauth, composer-php

I have some problems getting jenkins to do a composer update, because one of the composer dependencies is a private git repo, hosted on Github

I am also having problems getting the composer update command to work in the commandline:

```
$ cd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/JOB/workspace
$ ls -la auth.json
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jenkins jenkins 99 Aug  3 15:49 auth.json
$ cat auth.json
{
    "github-oauth" : {
        "github.com" : "<notAvailableOnSO>"
    }
}
$ composer update -n
```

Error:

```
Failed to clone the git@github.com:<Org>/<Project>.git repository, try running in interactive mode so that you can enter your GitHub credentials

[RuntimeException]
Failed to execute git clone --mirror 'https://***:***@github.com/<Org>/<Project>.git' '/var/lib/jenkins/.composer/cache/vcs/git-github.com-<Org>-<Project>.git/'
Cloning into bare repository '/var/lib/jenkins/.composer/cache/vcs/git-github.com-<Org>-<Project>.git'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://***:***@github.com/<Org>/<Project>.git/' not found
```

The project that I'm trying to update has this repositories setting in it's composer.json:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/<Org>/<Project>.git"
    }
]
```

Even without the -n (interactive mode), I can input the github oauth token and have composer report back that the token has been saved and still get the error.

Am I putting the auth.json in the wrong place, or should I do the authorisation differently?

(It is obviously not possible to publish proprietary source code on github for the sake of having a deployment work)

Comment: testing the ssh setup with the command
    $ ssh -T git@github.com

returns

Hi tasklift-jenkins! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.

Answer (score 0):

I got the "composer update" command to work (command line and via jenkins).

After actually reading the error message and understanding that the repository wasn't available for the user, logging into github, I solved my problem by ensuring that the github user actually was allowed read-access to the repository.

:)